# Windows Terminal and PowerShell - Custom Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-terminal

I have added in my PowerShell profile functions to set locations as following:

```
function myPath {set-location "D:\SomePath\"}
```

Now when I call it in Windows Terminal with PowerShell the command `myPath` it redirects to the specific one. With the command `start .` I can open this directory in Windows Explorer. Is there any way that I can introduce custom keyboard shortcuts that will open Window Explorer to the current directory like `Ctrl+E` to replace somehow `start .` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following, using the built-in `PSReadLine` module's **[`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler)** cmdlet:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'ctrl+e' { Invoke-Item $PWD.ProviderPath }
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> should then bring up the host platform's file browser, showing the current directory.

---

Note that an **alternative** to defining a keyboard shortcut is to **submit the following command**, which uses the built-in `ii` alias for the [`Invoke-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Invoke-Item) cmdlet:

```
ii .
```